# Send form info from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I am facing a problem and I am already stuck for ages, hopefully one of you can help me.

The Problem:
- I created a form in HTML and I connected Jquery to it in order to validate whether input is correct (also to give the user feedback whether answer is correct). When individuals press the submit button the information is also send to my database in phpMyadmin (this works.

The problem is, how can I make sure that the information is only send to my phpMyadmin database when al the input is correct? I know with jquery when all the input is correct but how can i connect this information to my php code?

To be more specific i created a javascript/ jquery variable like correct_answers which is 13 when all questions are correct (as I have 13 questions), but how can I send this information (which is in correct_answers) to php?, so that I can create an if condition within php in order to send the info yes or no?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you are looking to form validation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ N.B. that people can potentially bypass validation in JavaScript, so it is best to either validate on the server, or do both.

Comment: Can you post the jQuery code which validates the form?

Comment: First example here shows how it works: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the form submit event to wrap your validation logic with.  If the form passes validation do nothing and it will submit normally, if not display a notice and prevent the form's submission:

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function(e){
     var failed = false;
    // logic for validatiom

    // use event object to prevent submission
    if (failed) {
        alert('error in form');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, both for the correct answer and the speed! I am surprised by the simplicity and the fact that I could not find this solution. Did you search the web for this solution? As i am very interest how you found is so that I can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  jQuery has excellent documentation, check it out at http://api.jquery.com, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

client side:

```
<input type="hidden" name="correct_answers" id="correct_answers" value="0">

<javascript>
checkForm = function(){

...
...
$('#correct_answers').val = 13;
form.submit(); //-- or ajax();
});
```

server side:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['correct_answers']);die('nice!');
```

Comment: Is it pseudocode or what? There is no tag `<javascript>`, there is no property `.val` and so on...